# Find the equivalence class of: [(1,2)],[(2,3)] and [3,-1].

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In $ \mathbb{R^2}$ we consider the relation $(x,y)R(a,b)$ if and only if exists $n \in  \mathbb{Z} $ such that $n-1<y\leq n \ $ and $ n-1<b\leq n \  $. The relation is an equivalence relation.

Find the equivalence class of $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, and $(3,-1)$.

**[(1,2)]**

$ [(1,2)]=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} :(x,y)R(1,2) \}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} : n-1<y\leq n \ $ and $n-1<2\leq n \}  $

**[(2,3)]**

$ [(2,3)]=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} :(x,y)R(2,3) \}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} : n-1<y\leq n \ $ and $n-1<3\leq n \}  $

**[(3,-1)]**

$ [(3,-1)]=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} :(x,y)R(3,-1) \}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} : n-1<y\leq n \ $ and $n-1<-1\leq n \}  $

**Is correct my answer?**

Comment: You failed to mention what $n$ is in each of these three cases. Once you find what each "$n$" should be you will be able to describe the sets in a much clearer way.

Comment: The regions of $\Bbb R^2$ that these equivalence classes describe are sometimes colloquially referred to as "strips" or "bands."  Think of them like "thicker" horizontal lines.

Comment: I deleted it only because AlexR's answer addressed everything in my post and he was faster to type it. I've gone ahead and undeleted it since you've asked.

Comment: Anyway your answer is very helpful. Thanks again

Comment: @JohnGriffin can you check my representation in a graphical way of the quotient set please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having the same issue as before. You should start with something along the lines of
\begin{align*}
[(1,2)]
&= \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : (x,y)R(1,2)\} \\
&= \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2
    : \exists n\in\mathbb{Z}\ \text{satisfying}\ n-1 <y \le n\ \text{and}\ 
      n-1 < 2 \le n\}.
\end{align*}
Note the part "$\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}$ satisfying...". It's very important that you describe the variables you are using. In your case, the "$n$" in each of your sets was undefined.

Now from here you should notice that there is only one $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ which satisfies $n-1 < 2 \le n$, namely $n=2$.
This gives us the condition $1=2-1 < y \le 2$, or $y\in(1,2]$ whenever $(x,y)R(1,2)$.
Therefore $(x,y)R(1,2)$ if and only if $y\in(1,2]$, so that we can write
$$
[(1,2)] = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y\in(1,2]\} = \mathbb{R}\times (1,2].
$$
Doing the same thing you can find the equivalence classes $[(2,3)]$ and $[(3,-1)]$.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you've correctly applied the definition, but the intended answer was probably a simple description of the equivalence classes.

A note on terminology before deriving a simpler solution: $n$ is not quantified in your answers. Correctly, you would have to add $\exists n\in\mathbb Z$ to the set comprehensions. For example:
$$[(1,2)] = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: \color{red}{\exists n\in\mathbb Z \text{ s.t. }} n-1<y\le n \text{ and } n-1 < 2 \le n\}$$

Firstly, note that the relation is independet of $x$ and $a$, i.e. the first component is free.
This means, if $(x, y) R (a,b)$, so does $(x', y) R(a', b)$ for any $x', a' \in\mathbb R$.
Equivalence classes are therefor always of the form $\mathbb R \times A$ where $A$ is some subset of $\mathbb R$.

To further examine the definition, you will find that these sets $A$ are described by a whole number $n$:

> If $A_n := (n-1, n]$, then $\mathbb R \times A_n$ is an equivalence class of $R$.

The intended answers therefor are likely the following:

> $[(1,2)] = \mathbb R \times (1, 2]$
>  $[(2,3)] = \mathbb R \times (2, 3]$
>  $[(3,-1)] = \mathbb R \times (-2, -1]$

All of these are, of course, equivalent to your answer.

---

A slightly more general way to tackle such problems is finding a function $f$, such that $xRy \Leftrightarrow f(x) = f(y)$. In this case its $f=\lceil \cdot \rceil \circ \pi_2$ (first project on the second coordinate, then take the ceiling ($\lceil x\rceil = n \in \mathbb Z \Leftrightarrow n-1 < x \le n$).
The equivalence class of a point $x$ is then $ [x]_R = f^{-1} \circ f(x)$ (i.e. the preimage of the image under $f$)

Comment: Thank you so much. So then the geometrical representation of the quotient set is the Cartesian Plane?

Comment: @Daniel Not sure what you're after, but the quotient set is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ via $f$. Imagine taking the plane and cutting it into vertical stripes of width $1$ and then collapsing each strip to a single point.

Comment: Can  you check this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436631/represent-graficaly-the-quotient-set