# How to represent a certain quotient set in a graphical way.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In $ \mathbb{R^2}$ we consider the relation $(x,y)R(a,b)$ if and only if exists $n \in  \mathbb{Z} $ such that $n-1<y\leq n \ $ and $ n-1<b\leq n \  $. $ R$ is an equivalence relation.

**Represent in a graphical way**

a) $\mathbb{R} \times (n-1,n] $

b) the quotient set

Is my representation correct?

[image]

Comment: And is the quotient set a numerable set? I think it isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer $n$ in the definition of the equivalence relation defines precisely to what equivalence class an element lies. More precisely, there is a natural bijection $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^2/R$ onto $\mathbb{Z}$, which can be realized by mapping the equivalence class of an element $(x,y)$ to the integer $n$ satisfying $n-1 < y \le n$.

This is a well-defined injection because the $n$ satisfying the inequalities above is unique and
$$
[(x,y)] = [(x',y')]
\iff
\exists n\in\mathbb{Z}\ \text{s.t.}\ n-1<y,y'\le n
\iff
f([(x,y)]) = f([(x',y')])
$$
holds for every $(x,y),(x',y')\in\mathbb{R}^2$.
Since for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $f[(0,n)] = n$, we conclude that $f$ is a bijection.

Thus the "best" way to represent the quotient set $\mathbb{R}^2/R$ graphically would be to draw $\mathbb{Z}$. That is, draw a number line (i.e., $\mathbb{R}$) and put a dot at each integer. You can then label the dots by something like $$\ldots,[(0,-2)],[(0,-1)],[(0,0)],[(0,1)],[(0,2)],\ldots$$

Comment: and is the quotient set a countable set? I think it is not.

Comment: @Daniel By a numerable set, do you mean a countable set? If so, ask that same question of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable

Comment: @Daniel Exactly! And given the bijection in the answer above, we know that the cardinality of the quotient is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you so much John, you saved my life :)